# How do I debug this ArgumentException?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I'm developing a C#/Metro application and in the OnNavigatedTo-method of the main page, I'm asynchronously loading data into a ViewModel which is set as the DataContext of the Page. As the OnNaviagedTo-method finishes execution, this [exception occurs](http://i49.tinypic.com/68fw9w.png) 9 out of 10 times. The loading itself goes fine, its when I hit F5 on the last closing bracket of OnNavigatedTo it fails.

To summarize:

- ArgumentException with no InnerExceptiond and message "Value does not fall within expected range"
- No stacktrace
- No debug output in the output window which can help me

How do I debug this? Where do I start? The lack of a descriptive error message is really problematic. "Value dos not fall within expected range"... Which value? What range? What line of code or XML fails?

Comment: PS: Since it happens 9 of 10 times, I suspect the async loading is relevant. Maybe the UI framwork is traversing the list of objects I bind to when I start to change them? How can I in that case prevent that?

Comment: try putting a try catch block around the method you think is causing the error, then print the exception to the ouput console using system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(...) it will probably be more detailed